# Do I need a /boot partition in a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dual bot install on a "Late 2007" Core 2 Duo MacBook 3,1?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, macbook

I am reviving an old MacBook with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and everything seems to be going fine, I just wonder if I need a /boot partition.

The doc says that it is not needed on laptops bought past 2007 but does not really say if it's important for laptops before that date.

The MacBoook dates back to the end of 2007 (that [one](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.2-white-13-late-2007-santa-rosa-specs.html)), so what do you think ? Am I going to have problems if I don't have one or if I have one ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, and not important.

Comment: Think the main thing to think about is if you just want one root/ partition holding everything or a separate /root and /home.  /home will keep your data, if you need to reinstall/upgrade.  /root should be about 25+gb.  This does not mean you don't need backups, but you might not need to use them if /home is separate.